# Using ArcPy to copy/paste text boxes from template?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, layouts, text

I am in the process of generating hundreds of maps in ArcMap 10.3 from a few master templates. I recently found out that I have to add a small text box in the bottom-right hand corner of all the maps containing additional information (all the boxes will contain the same text and be placed in the exact same location).

Is there a way I can add the text box to the master templates and use Arcpy to copy & paste the text box on all the maps?

Trying to find a way not to do this manually.

Comment: are all these maps being generated from one mxd? or multiple?

Comment: They'll be based on several .mxds, but if it makes the answer to this question any easier, I can easily just put the text box in 1 master template and have Arcpy use that as the jumping-off point to copy/paste on all the rest.

Comment: You can't create new layout elements with arcpy, only copy and modify existing elements. You would have to tap into ArcObjects (which you can do through Python, although it's somewhat complicated) to move elements between maps or create new elements.

Comment: Thanks for the help, @phloem. I'll look into ArcObjects.

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround possible, if you already have got a textbox in your layout.
You can use the `.clone()` - function to copy and paste a textbox in your layout.
Now you can change the content with `.text` and use `.elementPositionX` and `.elementPositionY`
to move the Textbox to you desired place.
If you need to alter font, font size or else you can use [formating tags](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s800000017000000) to do so.

In the example below I also cloned a graphic rectangle and placed it around the new cloned textbox.

```
import arcpy

inputMap = r"D:\Textboxes.mxd"
outputMap = r"D:\Textboxes2.mxd"

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(inputMap)

# get elemets according to element-name
Textorig = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT","Textorig")[0]
Frame = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "GRAPHIC_ELEMENT","Frame")[0]

# clone elements
Textorig.clone("_copy")
Frame.clone("_copy")

# alter elements 
Textorigcopy = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT","Textorig_copy")[0]
Textorigcopy.text = '<FNT size = "36"><CLR red = "255"><BOL><ITA>New Text</ITA></BOL></CLR></FNT>'
Textorigcopy.elementPositionX = 6.8883
Textorigcopy.elementPositionY = 21.6488

Framecopy = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "GRAPHIC_ELEMENT","Frame_copy")[0]
Framecopy.elementPositionX = 6.7135
Framecopy.elementPositionY = 21.5169
Framecopy.elementWidth = 6.1354
Framecopy.elementHeight = 1.7808

mxd.saveACopy(outputMap)
del mxd
```

[image]